# Adding pin wrong place in mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am working with Google Map. My problem is when i touch the screen mapview is not adding pin exactly right place.Adding nearly Ycoordinate-50.

I added CustomitemzedOverlay too.

What is wrong with code?

Can anybody help me?

Code:

```
 public void AddPoint(Drawable drawable, MapView mapView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) (motionEvent.getX()),(int) (motionEvent.getY()));
        final MapController mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(16);
        CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(drawable, mapView);

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new CustomOverlayItem(p,"","",""));
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }




package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CustomItemizedOverlay<Item extends OverlayItem> extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<CustomOverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
        c = mapView.getContext();
    }

    public void addOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void removeOverlay(CustomOverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.remove(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected CustomOverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return m_overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return m_overlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, CustomOverlayItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(c, "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected BalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem> createBalloonOverlayView() {
        // use our custom balloon view with our custom overlay item type:
        return new CustomBalloonOverlayView<CustomOverlayItem>(getMapView().getContext(), getBalloonBottomOffset());
    }

}
```

Comment: if u r using itemized overlay , then i think ur issue is related to boundCenterBottom();

Comment: I update my code.What does it mean related boundCenterBottom().Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete tutorial on mapview : [comprehensive google maps tutorials](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

u can create an overlay class ; and in the `onDraw()` , u should use `getIntrinsicHeight()` `getIntrinsicWidth()/2`

Also here is a tutorial on [itemized overlays](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html) where u can use `boundCenterBottom()` to position your marker properly

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you when using [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) library. It takes me half a day to find a solution. Here's my fix:

On your CustomItemizedOverlay, let make the overlay in boundCenterBottom

```
public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker), mapView);
    c = mapView.getContext();
}
```

And in your Map Activty, when create marker drawable, let do a trick like this (thanks Cyril Mottier for his [Polaris mapview library](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/Polaris)):

```
drawable = MapViewUtils.boundMarkerCenterBottom(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin_holed_violet));
```

MapViewUtils is gotten from Polaris library. Here's its boundMarkerCenterBottom function:

```
public static Drawable boundMarkerCenterBottom(Drawable marker) {
    return boundMarker(marker, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
}
public static Drawable boundMarker(Drawable marker, int gravity) {
    if (marker == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final int width = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int height = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The given Drawable has no intrinsic width or height");
    }

    int left, top;

    switch (gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
        case Gravity.LEFT:
            left = 0;
            break;
        case Gravity.RIGHT:
            left = -width;
            break;
        case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
        default:
            left = -width / 2;
            break;
        }

    switch (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
        case Gravity.TOP:
            top = 0;
            break;
        case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
            top = -height / 2;
            break;
        case Gravity.BOTTOM:
        default:
            top = -height;
            break;
    }

    marker.setBounds(left, top, left + width, top + height);
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think the issue might be setting the zoom after getting the projection.  I actually.  There is a tutorial on doing exactly what you want on a blog I contribute to [AndroidDev101](http://androiddev101.com/2012/04/15/episode-5-mapviews-and-overlays/) that should give you what you need to accomplish the task of adding a point as well.

[Blog](http://www.androiddev101.com)